# Can a direct product $R\times X$ of two integral domains $R$ and $X$ ever be an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain, direct-product

Assuming we are using the standard definition of a direct product, I think this is never the case.

An integral domain is a commutative ring with unity that has no zero divisors. Just the fact that both $X$ and $R$ have a multiplicative identity element, allows us to pick two elements of this direct product set, specifically $(r, 0_X)$ and $(0_R, x)$ for any $r\in R, x\in X$ and we will always be able to get a zero as a product of two non-zero elements.

Am I correct here, or is there perhaps something that I'm missing?

Note that I did consider the case where both $R$ and $X$ are trivial, but by definition of integral domain, trivial rings cannot be considered as integral domains.

Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Specifically, $(1,0)\cdot(0,1)=0$.

Comment: @Berci yes that is the thing that ruins the integral domain properties. But that doesn't really answer my question. Is it *ever* possible for two integral domains' direct product to be an integral domain itself? By the way, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Luka: it completely answers your question. Berci's argument applies to every product of integral domains.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You are right. I misread what Berci wrote... My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

A product of rings is an integral domain if and only if exactly one of them is an integral domain and all the others are the zero ring. Otherwise there's indeed a phenomenon like $(1,0)\cdot (0,1)=(0,0)$.

*Added:* I should point out that my assertion works under the convention that the $0$ is not an integral domain: for, if it were, then the product of the empty family would be the "$0$ domain", but it wouldn't be true that exactly one of the rings in the family is a domain (since exactly zero of them are). So the correct formulation in the (non-standard) case where we allow $0$ to be a a domain would be that a product of rings is "domain-or-zero" if and only if all of them are domains-or-zero and at most one of them is non-zero.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. So I can assume that I was right in thinking that the direct product of two integral domains can never be an integral domain itself? Again, zero rings shouldn't be integral domains right? By the way thanks for the answer!

Comment: @LukaDuranovic You are right.